# Perl caching under Apache - Mutex during long load

Tags: perl, apache, caching

I have a large file I need to load into the cache (As a hash) which will be shared between perl processes. Loading the data into cache takes around 2 seconds, but we have over 10 calls per second.

Does using the compute method cause other processes to be locked out?
Otherwise, I would appreciate suggestions on how to manage the load process so that there's a guaranteed lock during load and only one load process happening!

Thanks!

Comment: What is your execution environment? Are you using mod_perl and, if so, which version? Are these processes independent CGI programs?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the guaranteed lock, but you could use memcached with a known key as a mutex substitute (as of this writing, you haven't said what your "cache" is). If the value for the key is false, set it to true, start loading, and then return the result.

For the requests happening during that time, you could either busy-wait, or try using a [503 "Service Unavailable"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-70) status with a few seconds in the Retry-After field. I'm not sure of the browser support for this.

As a bonus, using a time-to-live of, say, 5 minutes on the mutex key will cause the entire file to be reloaded every 5 minutes. Otherwise, if you have a different reason for reloading the file, you will need to manually delete the key.